# Google chart vertical axis strange label

Tags: charts, google-visualization, material-design

I have made a Google column chart.
It displays ok. but the vertical axis label is showing an unit that I never set myself. 
here is the screen shot.

[image]

I don't understand **why it displays "1 td" instead of 1000 , "1,2 td" instead of 1200.**

Here is my code:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ….
            ….
]);

var options = {
          title: 'My Test',
 };

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);

<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

my code has nothing special part for the vertical axis and I used from google chart gallery. **why it gets 'td' unit for vertical axis even I didn't set myself?
Is it Google column chart default option?**
I try to manipulate the vertical axis value with `vAxis:`. but no luck.
Any advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, when using [material bar charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Material), the `y`-axis (vAxis) default format is `short`, meaning showing `td` for thousands and so on. To reset this set `format` to `''` :

```js
var options = {
  axes : {
    y : {
      all : {
        format : {
           pattern : ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}    
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sfc9aLd4/**

But the material charts are still in beta, and a lot of the options are yet not documented or documented poorly. Luckily we can use the google visualization options object layout and convert it with `convertOptions(options)` :

```js
var options = {
    vAxis : {
        format : '' //or #####
    }
}    
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Will result in the same as above `axes : { ... }`
demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3aq7gucd/**

---

With material charts there seems to be some differences for `format`. `'none'` is now `''`. `decimal` should be changed to `####.##` or likewise. `scientific`, `currency` and `percent` works as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works and good explanation!! I never find anywhere about this.